# postValue Method of MutableLiveData returning null

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I was implementing Mvvm model and tried to use MutableLiveData to listen for changes.
There are two methods for this

1. setValue() - Sets the value. If there are active observers, the value will be dispatched to them.This method must be called from the main thread.
2. postValue() - use postValue when you need set a value from a background thread.

Here is my code what I was trying and I am getting null when I use postValue and if I use setValue It is working fine.

**ViewModel**

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Model>> modelsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MainActivityViewModel() {
    modelsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Model>> getModelsLiveData() {
    return modelsLiveData;
}

public void setModelsLiveData(final List<Model> modelsList) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.i("LIVE_DATA_TEST", Thread.currentThread().toString());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                modelsLiveData.postValue(modelsList);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();


}
```

**MainActivity**

```
 ActivityMainBinding activityBinding = DataBindingUtil
            .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main, new AppDataBindingComponent<>(this));
    MainActivityViewModel viewModel = new MainActivityViewModel();
    activityBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);

    Log.i("LIVE_DATA_TEST", "onCreate: "+ Thread.currentThread());

    List<Model> modelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    modelsList.add(new Model("Suzuki Swift", 2761111));
    modelsList.add(new Model("Renoult Megan", 3679060));
    modelsList.add(new Model("Fiat Panda", 4638764));
    modelsList.add(new Model("Fiat 500", 1234567));
    modelsList.add(new Model("Toyota Land Crouser", 9876543));

    viewModel.setModelsLiveData(modelsList);
```

**Layout**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.matanmarciano.mvvmlivedata.viewmodels.MainActivityViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/models_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:items="@{viewModel.modelsLiveData}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**DataBindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter({"items"})
public void items(final RecyclerView recyclerView, List<Model> models) {
    Log.i("LIVE_DATA_TEST", "Let's see if this method is reached" + models);

    // TODO: update recyclerView adapter...
}
```

**Logs**
This is what I am getting

```
I/LIVE_DATA_TEST: onCreate: Thread[main,5,main]
I/LIVE_DATA_TEST: Thread[Thread-4,5,main]
I/LIVE_DATA_TEST: Let's see if this method is reached null // null I am getting here when using postValue.
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add layout code as well?

Comment: I have updated please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add setLifecycleOwner for subscribe to liveData from data binding.

```
ActivityMainBinding activityBinding = DataBindingUtil
            .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main, new AppDataBindingComponent<>(this));
activityBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata